# Need to place user input from a prompt box (Javascript) into a String variable. How do I do so?

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver

I have this following code that will create a prompt box in a Mozilla web browser:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.promptResponse=prompt('Please enter site code:')");
```

What I need is the user input, that is placed into a String variable:
ie. String userInput = 'values of from the prompt box (eg. site code)';

Can someone help me write the code for it? I tried many different ways. It didn't work. Below was one of the ways I tried:

Method 1:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(5000);
String userInput = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");       
alert.accept();
```

Comment: Java != Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Using prompt will allow you to get the input from user.

```
var str = prompt("enter your site code...");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps! :))

```js
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(5000);
String userInput = (String) js.executeScript("return prompt('Please enter site code:')");       
alert.accept();
```

Comment: I don't see any differences? Did you forget to amend something?

Comment: `js.executeScript("return prompt('Please enter site code:')");`

Comment: It didn't work as expected. But I manage to tweak it to make it work!!! Thanks though! Much appreciated. Below is the code that works now:

    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    alert.accept();
    String code = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");
    System.out.println("code is: "+code);

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that enabled me to get the user input. Thanks to all that helped!

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(5000);
alert.accept();
String code = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");
System.out.println("code is: "+code);
```